# Formatting Date in Title

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

I have figured out how to get a date (from a report parameter) in my title:

```
[@Start]
```

Annoying that I cannot do "this" which is what I really want to do

```
[@Start] to [@End]
```

But I can deal with that; it just means 3 titles instead of one.

However, what I cannot seem to figure out is how to format the date:

I Get: 11/13/2011 12:00:00 AM

I want: Nov 13th

I could live with 11/13/2011

Answer (score 0):

For the suffix I recommend to use the `switch` function:

```
=Format(Parameters!Start.Value, "MMM-dd") + 
    Switch(Format(Parameters!Start.Value, "dd") >= 11 And Format(Parameters!Start.Value, "dd") <= 13 , "th",
        Right(Format(Parameters!Start.Value, "dd"), 1) = "1", "st", 
        Right(Format(Parameters!Start.Value, "dd"), 1) = "2", "nd", 
        Right(Format(Parameters!Start.Value, "dd"), 1) = "3", "rd",
        1 = 1, "th")
```

Or you can make a user function to do the same...

Answer (score -1):

It took awhile to figure out that the "expr" field can be very complex.

The following gives me very close to what I need:

=Format(Parameters!Start.Value, "MMM-dd") + " to " + Format(Parameters!End.Value, "MMM-dd")